# Remove default exception message and print only custom message in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, datetime

**Python 2.7**: I am trying to create method which check whether input time is according to format as `YYYY-MM-DD`. If the date is not as per given format, send user custom message that **"Please change the format as YYYY-MM-DD"**. If the date is as per format please check whether it is greater than today's date, if not again send user custom message. In all the cases I just need to come out of the method sending custom message and not to break the program.

```
def validate_timeline(time):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d')
        try:
            time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d')
            dat = datetime.datetime.today()
            if dat > time:
                print("Please enter the future date")
                raise Exception("Choose the date greater than today's date")
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")

    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
```

I am still getting default exception message with custom message.

```
Exception !! Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD Traceback :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "My_file.py", line 511, in <module>
    validate_timeline(time)
  File "My_file.py", line 62, in validate_timeline
    raise ValueError("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
ValueError: Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD
```

**Desired output:**

```
Enter the command: set timeout 2017-09- to file
"Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD"
Enter the command:
```

Here the program should ask to enter the command(raw_input) again and should not come out of the program.

**code:**

```
 elif(condition):
            lis = opt.split()
            timeline = lis[2]
            user = lis[4]
            grp = lis[7]
            validate_timeline(timeline)
            with open("test.txt","r") as f:
```

Comment: Please show what output you _want_ to get instead. The output is showing exactly the exception message you use in your `raise` statements.

Comment: @tobias_k I have added, let me know if it make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you `raise` the exception seems fine. The problem is probably on the calling side. If you do not want those stack traces to print and the program to crash, you have to handle the exception yourself and just print it.

```
cmd = input("Enter the command:")
try:
    validate_timeline(cmd)
    # do other things
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Example output:

```
Enter the command: not a real date
Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't raise those specific exceptions, instead write your custom message to continue with the program execution

```
def validate_timeline(time):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d')
        try:
            time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d')
            dat = datetime.datetime.today()
            if dat > time:
                print("Please enter the future date")
                #raise Exception("Choose the date greater than today's date")
        except ValueError:
            #raise ValueError("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
            print("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")

    except ValueError:
        #raise ValueError("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
        print("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Comment: `pass` is not needed here. `pass` is just "no operation" used to indicate an empty block.

Comment: @Van Peer If I add pass, it will throw my custom message removing all default message but sametime continue executing script and adding the wrong format in file

Comment: @cyborg isn't that what you were expecting? you can try without `pass` as well.